# Right way of stopping search on sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

helps right way of stopping search service on sharepoint foundation 2014, steop by step. Thanks You

```
<html><html>
```

Comment: give us more details,what you mean by stopping the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can start or stop a service application from central administration -- the reference is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704549(v=office.15).aspx

> To start or stop a service by using Central Administration
>
> 1. Confirm that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint Group
> 2. On the the SharePoint Central Administration website, click System Settings.
> 3. On the System Settings page, in the Servers section, click Manage services on server.
> 4. To change the server on which you want to start or stop the service, on the Server menu, click Change Server, and then click the
>      server name that you want.
> 5. By default, only configurable services are displayed. To view all services, on the View menu, click All.
> 6. To start or stop a service, click Start or Stop in the Action column of the relevant service.
> 7. Click OK to start or stop the service.

You can also do this through PowerShell - the procedure is described in the same link as above